# How do I gain gold efficiently?

Tags: rodeo-stampede

In [*Rodeo Stampede: Sky Zoo Safari*](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yodo1.rodeo.safari&hl=en), what's  good way to optimize gold profits in the sky zoo and gold gain when riding animals in the savanna?

Any good strategies on habitat upgrade order in the sky zoo,  animals that I should focus on collecting in the savanna, and other gold collecting strategies?

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty much in the beginning of the game, so take my answer with a grain of salt. The best way I found so far is:

1. Find new animals for your zoo at all costs, since more animals means more earnings from visitors.
2. Try solving two or three missions at once, then doubling your income by watching an advertising.
3. Each animal has a level tier where income from visitors for that animal is doubled. The lower ones (level 4 or below) are well worth it.
4. Ostriches for their level 4 or 5 expansion get the ability to get triple payout from the chests during a run. As soon as I got this I tried to use ostriches exclusively during money-runs. Vultures can actually get 5 times payout, but I find it almost impossible to hit a box with a bucking vulture.
5. If you follow my ostrich strategy you might also want to get the expansions where you get extra coins for ostriches running at max speed (it's not a lot of money you get, but an extra 10 to 20 coins per run can sometimes go a long way) and the expansion where they throw you when colliding at max speed (gives you a chance to continue your run)
6. Travel as soon as possible, since travelling means more new animals, which goes back to my first point.

Answer (score 2):

As already said, finding new animals is the best way to go. To do this you should:

1. Look for the endangered species every day
2. Focus space upgrades on "Add X more rare ANIMALS to the stampede"
3. Fully upgrade habitats to "Add a new ANIMAL to the stampede"
4. Try and travel large distances to more easily find new undiscovered species
5. Complete boss missions when they become available

In terms of earning coins during gameplay rather than from selling tickets, upgrading animals to give you coins is the way to go. The best animals I've found for this are:

1. Rhinos, elephants, and yaks earn coins by smashing objects. I find that starting with one of these and smashing everything allows me to earn a reasonable amount of coins within the first ~400m.
2. Llamas, camels, and giraffes earn coins by jumping far from them, this is most useful in the mountains due to llamas being so common, and by jumping long distances from llama to llama you can easily rack up coins.
3. Ostriches, wolves, and emus earn coins by running fast. But ostriches and wolves also have the bonus of getting 3x money from crates, making them more useful than emus.
4. Vultures, toucans, eagles, and flying foxes earn coins whilst swooping. This alone isn't too profitable, but vultures, toucans, and eagles have a 5x crate bonus too.
5. Sheep earn coins whilst bucking, but as they push other sheep aside it is easier to stay on them for long distances in the Outback, this can earn upwards of 1000 coins per run.
6. Lions, crocodiles, tigers, bears, and drop bears earn coins by eating other animals. This often isn't as profitable as other methods, but if one of these animals is available when a more desirable animal isn't they can prove useful.

Lastly, baby animals can give bonuses to coins earned from missions and from crates. For instance:

- The baby Earl of Phant gives 8% more coins from missions, and has the passive ability of 2% more coins from crates. The passive ability alone makes it worth getting.
- The baby Rhino makes crates give 20% more coins
- The baby Boaring gives 12% more coins from missions

I would recommend having a baby equipped which gives a bonus to crates normally, and switching it to a baby which gives a bonus to missions when attempting missions.

I would also recommend just trying to hit any crates you find along the way.